# Publishing into two repositories

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to be able to publish to 2 repositories.

One remote repository that I can publish to using `sbt publish`:

```
publishTo := Some("Remote repository" at "htpp://...")
```

One local repository (custom directory within project's root) that I can publish to using `sbt publish-local`. I couldn't find a way to override the default `${ivy.home}/local`. I tried:

```
externalResolvers += Resolver.file("local", file("mydir"))
```

But that didn't work. I'm guessing that's because I append at the end of the sequence, so I'm not overriding the default one.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have a list of proxy repositories in `~/.sbt/repositories`. So I want to keep them too.

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite instead of appending to externalResolvers you could use

```
val remoteRepo = "my-public" at "http://my-nexus-server/content/groups/public/"
val localRepo = Resolver.file("local", file("mydir")) 
externalResolvers := Seq(remoteResolver, localRepo)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I also have `~/.sbt/repositories` so I can't use your suggestion.